# selenium webdriver Failed to connect to localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:43842 exception

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using IE Webdriver for my testng suite but intermittently i am getting `Failed to connect to localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:43842 exception`. Any suggestions if you have encountered this issue previously..

```
09:54:17.959 [main] DEBUG ePOSUAT.EPOSSuite - Java security warning pop-out and accept checkbox detected.

[log] CLICK on L[572,469]@S(0) (540 msec)

09:54:18.667 [main] INFO  ePOSUAT.EPOSSuite - Java security warning pop-out: accept checkbox detected and clicked.

[log] CLICK on L[818,470]@S(0) (532 msec)

09:54:19.564 [main] INFO  ePOSUAT.EPOSSuite - Java security warning pop-out and Run button detected and clicked.

09:54:19.564 [main] DEBUG ePOSUAT.EPOSSuite - Java security warning pop-out handled once and done.

09:54:20.029 [main] INFO  ePOSUAT.EPOSSuite - Server path: NHPEPOSVDAPP01Cell01\eposuat01Node01\eposuat-Svr02

09:54:27.099 [main] DEBUG ePOSUAT.EPOSSuite - Stacktrace:

org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:43842

Build info: version: '3.14.0', revision: 'aacccce0', time: '2018-08-02T20:05:20.749Z'

System info: host: 'IN40003555-0', ip: '10.235.34.54', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_212'

Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver

09:54:27.099 [main] ERROR ePOSUAT.EPOSSuite - Exception: java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:43842

Build info: version: '3.14.0', revision: 'aacccce0', time: '2018-08-02T20:05:20.749Z'

System info: host: 'IN40003555-0', ip: '10.235.34.54', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_212'

Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver



===============================================

EPOSSuite

Total tests run: 10, Failures: 1, Skips: 8

Configuration Failures: 1, Skips: 0

===============================================


Second error

Error 1:
[RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 6.14.3
18:37:06.241 [main] INFO  ePOSUAT.EPOSSuite - Browser type selected: IE
Started InternetExplorerDriver server (32-bit)
3.14.0.0
Listening on port 25191
Log level is set to TRACE
Log file is set to C:\Users\hu1262e\Desktop\Java_WorkSpace\SeleniumTest\logs\IEDriver.log
Only local connections are allowed
18:37:27.491 [main] ERROR ePOSUAT.EPOSSuite - Exception during initialization of web driver: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Timed out waiting for driver server to start.
Build info: version: '3.14.0', revision: 'aacccce0', time: '2018-08-02T20:05:20.749Z'
System info: host: 'IN40003946-9073', ip: '192.168.193.12', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_212'
Driver info: driver.version: InternetExplorerDriver
18:37:27.594 [main] INFO  ePOSUAT.EPOSSuite - Test case 1 - Login to ePOS

===============================================
EPOSSuite
Total tests run: 2, Failures: 1, Skips: 1
Configuration Failures: 1, Skips: 0
===============================================
```

Comment: Check this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/52110808/1728790

Answer (score 0):

You can give try with normal Selenium driver.get(String url) function.

> driver.get(“localhost:56763“);