# Protractor Fails to Run Tests

Tags: angularjs, selenium, protractor

I have an angularjs project that I am trying to set up protractor with. I'll eventually be doing it in angular 5 as well but this current project is angularjs. I'm on Windows Server 2016. The steps I took were:

Installed protractor globally
`npm install protractor -g`

Updated webdriver-manager

`webdriver-manager update`

Started webdriver-manager

`webdriver-manager start`

My `protractor.conf.js` located in in test folder

```
exports.config = {
    seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
    specs: ['e2e/**/*.js'],
    capabilities: {
        browserName: 'chrome'
    }
};
```

When I run protractor from commandline

`protractor test/protractor.conf.js`
I get the following error:

```
E:\DemoApp>protractor test/protractor.conf.js

[16:36:25] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[16:36:25] I/hosted - Using the selenium server at http://localhost:4444/wd/hub
[16:36:45] E/launcher - Timed out waiting for driver server to start.
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:53'
System info: host: 'APC', ip: 'x.x.x.x', os.name: 'Windows Server 2016', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_231'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
[16:36:45] E/launcher - WebDriverError: Timed out waiting for driver server to start.
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:53'
System info: host: 'APC', ip: 'x.x.x.x', os.name: 'Windows Server 2016', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_231'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
    at Object.checkLegacyResponse (C:\Users\btime\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\error.js:546:15)
    at parseHttpResponse (C:\Users\btime\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\http.js:509:13)
    at C:\Users\btime\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\http.js:441:30
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
From: Task: WebDriver.createSession()
    at Function.createSession (C:\Users\btime\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver.js:769:24)
    at Function.createSession (C:\Users\btime\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\chrome.js:761:15)
    at createDriver (C:\Users\btime\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\index.js:170:33)
    at Builder.build (C:\Users\btime\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\index.js:626:16)
    at Hosted.getNewDriver (C:\Users\btime\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\built\driverProviders\driverProvider.js:53:33)
    at Runner.createBrowser (C:\Users\btime\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\built\runner.js:195:43)
    at C:\Users\btime\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\built\runner.js:339:29
    at _fulfilled (C:\Users\btime\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\q\q.js:834:54)
    at C:\Users\btime\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\q\q.js:863:30
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (C:\Users\btime\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\q\q.js:796:13)
[16:36:45] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 199
```

Here's what `webdriver-manager` reported when erroring

```
E:\DemoApp>webdriver-manager start
[16:33:35] I/start - java -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver=C:\Users\btime\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium\geckodriver-v0.26.0.exe -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=C:\Users\btime\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium\chromedriver_79.0.3945.36.exe -jar C:\Users\btime\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium\selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar -port 4444
[16:33:35] I/start - seleniumProcess.pid: 3728
16:33:36.252 INFO [GridLauncherV3.parse] - Selenium server version: 3.141.59, revision: e82be7d358
16:33:36.351 INFO [GridLauncherV3.lambda$buildLaunchers$3] - Launching a standalone Selenium Server on port 4444
2020-01-29 16:33:36.408:INFO::main: Logging initialized @415ms to org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.log.StdErrLog
16:33:36.689 INFO [WebDriverServlet.<init>] - Initialising WebDriverServlet
16:33:36.841 INFO [SeleniumServer.boot] - Selenium Server is up and running on port 4444
16:36:25.573 INFO [ActiveSessionFactory.apply] - Capabilities are: {
  "browserName": "chrome",
  "count": 1
}
16:36:25.575 INFO [ActiveSessionFactory.lambda$apply$11] - Matched factory org.openqa.selenium.grid.session.remote.ServicedSession$Factory (provider: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService)
16:36:45.599 ERROR [OsProcess.checkForError] - org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: -1073741819 (Exit value: -1073741819)
```

`webdriver-manager` says I am up-to-date as well

```
E:\DemoApp>webdriver-manager update
[16:46:25] I/update - selenium standalone: file exists C:\Users\btime\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium\selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar
[16:46:25] I/update - selenium standalone: selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar up to date
[16:46:25] I/update - chromedriver: file exists C:\Users\btime\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium\chromedriver_79.0.3945.36.zip
[16:46:25] I/update - chromedriver: unzipping chromedriver_79.0.3945.36.zip
[16:46:25] I/update - chromedriver: chromedriver_79.0.3945.36.exe up to date
[16:46:25] I/update - geckodriver: file exists C:\Users\btime\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium\geckodriver-v0.26.0.zip
[16:46:25] I/update - geckodriver: unzipping geckodriver-v0.26.0.zip
[16:46:26] I/update - geckodriver: geckodriver-v0.26.0.exe up to date
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/a/52110808/10836734

Comment: @DublinDev unfortunately it did not resolve the issue. I had a higher version of Java but went ahead and updated to latest JDK 8. Already had latest Selenium and ChromeDriver from webdriver-manager update. Rebooted system too.

Answer (score 0):

try with the below command to start the webdriver instead of webdriver-manager start

**java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver="chromedriver.exe" -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar -port 4444**

Comment: When I do that I get `Error: Unable to access jarfile selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar`

Comment: Even if I edit to put full path like so:

`java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver="chromedriver.exe" -jar "C:\Users\btime\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium\selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar" -port 4444` the server starts but when I go to run tests I get `[01:58:41] E/launcher - SessionNotCreatedError: Unable to create new service: ChromeDriverService` as part of the error

Comment: can u try the below  command 1. cd C:\Users\btime\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium\      2.  java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar -port 4444

Comment: @NirmalKurmar back to `E/launcher - Timed out waiting for driver server to start.`