# Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Timed out waiting for driver server to start

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Getting an exception while running an selenium script.
Operation performed to resolve the issue-

1. Changed driver version.
2. Tried changing selenium version.

> Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Timed out waiting for driver server to start.
> Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:48'
> System info: host: 'DESKTOP-GCUE5OF', ip: '192.168.43.125', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_73'
> Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
> at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.waitUntilAvailable(DriverService.java:202)
> at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.start(DriverService.java:188)
> at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:79)
> at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
> at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:213)
> at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
> at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.(ChromeDriver.java:181)
> at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.(ChromeDriver.java:168)
> at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.(ChromeDriver.java:123)
> at RebotClass.Up.main(Up.java:19)
> Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker$TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for [http://localhost:28544/status] to be available after 20004 ms
> at org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker.waitUntilAvailable(UrlChecker.java:100)
> at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.waitUntilAvailable(DriverService.java:197)
> ... 9 more
> Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
> at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
> at com.google.common.util.concurrent.SimpleTimeLimiter.callWithTimeout(SimpleTimeLimiter.java:156)
> at org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker.waitUntilAvailable(UrlChecker.java:75)
> ... 10 more

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\Driver\\chromedriver.exe");
        //System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\Ankita_Workspace(2019-12)\\Selenium_Webdriver\\UploadFile\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("http://demo.automationtesting.in/Register.html");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
         Robot robot = new Robot();
           driver.findElement(By.id("imagesrc")).click();
     
            robot.setAutoDelay(2000);
     
            StringSelection selection = new StringSelection("D:\\Files\\demo.txt");
            Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(selection,null);
     
            robot.setAutoDelay(1000);
     
            robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
            robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
     
            robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
            robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
     
            robot.setAutoDelay(1000);
     
            robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
            robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
        
    }
```

Comment: Could you share the code

Comment: Please find code as well

Answer (score 0):

Try updating Jdk to the latest version and try if it resolves the issue
 `java.version: '1.8.0_73'`
The Version you are using is quite old
You can also refer this Question-> [org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Timed out waiting for driver server to start. Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: 'unknown'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52110521/org-openqa-selenium-webdriverexception-timed-out-waiting-for-driver-server-to-s)

Comment: I have tried updating the newer version with JDK-1.8.0_261 again the same error..