# Selenide Driver not starting on Jenkins

Tags: java, selenium, jenkins, selenide

My tests run successfully on my local pc, but when I try to run them on my physical remote PC, using a jenkins job, I get the following message on some tests. Many tests run fine, some pass, but most are skipped or failed with this error message:

```
Timed out waiting for driver server to start.
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'XXXXX', ip: '172.22.103.211', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_311'
Driver info: driver.version: SelenideDriver
selenide.url: URL_OF_ENVIRONENT
selenide.baseUrl: URL_OF_ENVIRONENT
```

Comment: How is Jenkins configured? This really doesn't say much.

Comment: It is unable to instantiate more instances of the Driver. See if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52110521/org-openqa-selenium-webdriverexception-timed-out-waiting-for-driver-server-to-s